# Ошибка при сборке libjpeg-turbo с cmake

Tags: компиляция, cmake, сборка

Устанавливаю модуль [Image::Scale](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Scale) для Perl на Windows 7. Он требует сборку библиотеки libjpeg-tubo. По [инструкции](https://github.com/andygrundman/Image-Scale/blob/master/README.win32) установил visual studio 2005, cygwin, nmake и cmake, распаковал архив с библиотекой. Потом выполняю команду в cygwin-терминале:

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
CMake Error: Could not create named generator NMake Makefiles

Generators
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  KDevelop3                    = Generates KDevelop 3 project files.
  KDevelop3 - Unix Makefiles   = Generates KDevelop 3 project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2005? А CMake какой версии? Какой-нибудь 2.4?

Comment: @arrowd, Версии: vc 2005, cmake 3.6.2, nmake 10.00.30319.01, cygwin 2.7.9

Answer (score 0):

Нужно установить [CMake для Windows](https://cmake.org/download/). Во время установки ткните опцию "Add CMake to the system PATH for all users".

Comment: Поставил. Запускаю в обычном терминале (не cygwin), ошибка: "The C compiler identification is unknown". Вот полный вывод: https://pastebin.com/V0cbbrHA